# Change attr in a message queue to O_NONBLOCK while a process is blocked

Tags: c, posix, message-queue

I have some processes using POSIX message queues and when error handling I want all of them to close. The trouble is, sometimes they don't finish on their own, and get blocked on mq_send when the queue is full (or on mq_receive when it is empty). Upon reading the documentation thoroughly, I noticed that there is a way to stop that blocking, namely setting the `O_NONBLOCK` flag with `mq_setattr()`. While most of the time the process that receives the error should be quick enough with setting the flag so that the processes never hang up to wait on it, one cannot be sure that this is the case. So I wondered if the processes that already wait will be woken up when the attribute is set to non-blocking, and I wrote the following program that verified that it didn't. Is the program correct about that? Can anything be done about processes waiting aside from manually calling `mq_receive()` to artificially lower the message count when `mq_maxmsg == mq_curmsgs` or sending a signal to them?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void system_err (char* fmt, ...) {
    va_list fmt_args;
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: ");
    va_start(fmt_args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, fmt_args);
    va_end (fmt_args);
    fprintf(stderr," (%d; %s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
int main() {
    struct mq_attr a;
    a.mq_flags = O_NONBLOCK;
    char bfr[819300];
    unsigned int prio = 69;
    int x;
    switch (fork()) {
        case -1:
            system_err("oops");
            break;
        case 0:
            sleep(1);
            x = mq_open("/lol", O_RDWR);
            if (x == -1) {
                system_err("childoops");
                return -1;
            }
            x = mq_receive(x, bfr, sizeof(bfr), &prio);
            if (x == -1) {
                system_err("receiveoops");
                return -1;
            }
            printf("childfin: %d %s %d\n", x, bfr, prio);
            break;
        default:
        x = mq_open("/lol", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0755, NULL);
        if (x == -1) {
            system_err("parentoops");
            return -1;
        }
        mq_getattr(x, &a);
        printf("flag:%ld\n\n", a.mq_flags);
        a.mq_flags = O_NONBLOCK;
        sleep(5);
        if (mq_setattr(x, &a, NULL)) {
            system_err("setattr");
        }
        mq_getattr(x, &a);
        printf("flag:%ld\n\n", a.mq_flags);
        printf("parentwait");
        fflush(stdout);
        wait(0);
        printf("parentfin");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Setting O_NONBLOCK in one process would not affect another process. I’d say sending a signal is the way to go.

Comment: So O_NONBLOCK is an attribute local to the processes (and their descriptors), rather that a global one for the queue?

Comment: @algrid forgot to send mention

Comment: Yes, it’s a property of descriptor - private to the process.